# How to fetch data from mongodb passing query object by async function in component?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, get, fetch, svelte

I want to fetch (GET) a specific object from my mongodb database and I' not very successful with it.

(using kit @0.0.1 and vite v2.9.14)

I use a fetch async function to make a GET request which hits /place endpoint and its get method:

src/routes/place/index.ts endpoint:

```
 export async function get({ request }: any) {
    try {
        const dbConnection = await connectToDatabase();
        const db = dbConnection.db;

        const collection = await db.collection('Places');
        const query = await collection.findOne(request);
        return {
            status: 200,
            body: {
                query
            }
        };
    } catch (err: any) {
        return {
            status: 500,
            body: {
                error: err.message
            }
        };
    }
}
```

function in src/routes/components/places_card.svelte component:

```
    async function fetchPlace() {
        const params = new URLSearchParams({ xid: 'N340026548' });
        try {
            await fetch(`/place?${params}`, {
                method: 'GET'
            })
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((as) => console.log(as));
        } catch (err: any) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    }
```

the query returns me null every time, I can't find a way to pass search parameters from above function to my endpoint. I've tried accessing the query url in various found ways. Could someone please explain how I could do that ? I would be very grateful. I'm new to backend and svelte in general.